# How to set state of the value when using react-rating component in my form?

Tags: reactjs, setstate, react-rating

I'm using React Rating (https://github.com/dreyescat/react-rating)
and I'm not sure how to set state for the values for my 2 ratings. The other fields are fine.

I'm able to get the values to show in console. I don't know how to set state in handleRatingChange().

Also, when I fill out the other fields after I have done the ratings, the ratings resets.

Here is my code:

```
var Rating = require('react-rating')

class Assignment extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      form: {
        site: '',
        facilityRate: '',
        staffRate: '',
        theList: 'off'
      }
    }
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const formState = Object.assign({}, this.state.form);
    formState[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ form: formState });
    console.log(formState);
  }

  handleRatingChange(rating) {
    console.log('rating', rating);
  }

  render() {
    return (

      <Grid>
        <PageHeader id='header'>
          Track your assignment <small className='subtitle'>Let us make a record of your assignment.</small>
        </PageHeader>

        <form id='assignment-form'>

          <h3>Record your assignment</h3>

          <Row>
            <Col xs={5} md={5}>
              <FormGroup>
                <ControlLabel id='site'>Site Name</ControlLabel>
                <FormControl type='text' name='site'
                  onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
                  value={this.state.form.site}
                />
              </FormGroup>

              <FormGroup>
                <ControlLabel id='facilityRate'>Rate the Facility</ControlLabel><br />
                <Rating
                  name='facilityRate'
                  emptySymbol={<img src='../star-empty.png' className='icon' alt='empty star' />}
                  fullSymbol={<img src='../star-full.png' className='icon' alt='filled star' />}
                  onChange={this.handleRatingChange} />
              </FormGroup>

              <FormGroup>
                <ControlLabel id='staffRate'>Rate the Staff</ControlLabel><br />
                <Rating
                  name='staffRate'
                  emptySymbol={<img src='../star-empty.png' className='icon' alt='empty star' />}
                  fullSymbol={<img src='../star-full.png' className='icon' alt='filled star' />}
                  onChange={this.handleRatingChange} />
              </FormGroup>

              <FormGroup>
                <ControlLabel id='theList'>The List
                          <br /><i>Add it to my favorites.</i>
                </ControlLabel><br />
                <Checkbox
                  name='theList'
                  checked={this.state.theList}
                  onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}>Add to The List
                            </Checkbox>
              </FormGroup>
            </Col>
          </Row>

          <Row>
            <Col xs={5} md={5}>
              <Button type='submit' className='btn btn-secondary' id='submit'>Submit Assignment</Button>
            </Col>
          </Row>


        </form>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an initial rating property, for example initialRating={this.state.facilityRating} for the facilityRate Rating and then initialRating={this.state.staffRating} for the staffRate Rating.

```
<Rating name='facilityRate' 
    emptySymbol={<img src='../star-empty.png' 
    className='icon' alt='empty star' />}
    initialRating={this.state.form.facilityRate}
    fullSymbol={<img src='../star-full.png' className='icon' 
    alt='filled star' />}
    onChange={this.handleStaffRatingChange} />

<Rating name='staffRate' 
        emptySymbol={<img src='../star-empty.png' 
        className='icon' alt='empty star' />}
        initialRating={this.state.form.staffRate}
        fullSymbol={<img src='../star-full.png' className='icon' 
        alt='filled star' />}
        onChange={this.handleStaffRatingChange} />
```

It's also important to have a default value in your state, since at the beginning, it's going to be undefined.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      form: {
        site: '',
        facilityRate: '', <-- Sets the initial value for facility
        staffRate: '', <-- Sets the initial value for staff
        theList: 'off'
      },
    }
  }
```

Then split your rating function into two functions.

```
handleStaffRatingChange = (rating) => {
    this.setState({...this.state, form: {...this.state.form, staffRate: rating}});
}

handleFacilityRatingChange = (rating) => {
    this.setState({...this.state, form: {...this.state.form, facilityRate: rating}});
}
```

The reason we did this is so that each function will alter a specific area in the state.  Each rating has to look at the state to determine what it's value is, therefore they cannot be the same value in the state.  The handleStaffRatingChange targets this.state.form.staffRate and handleFacilityRatingChange targets this.state.form.facilityRate.

It is possible to design a single function to handle both, but since you're fairly new to react, I'm don't want to throw too much at you at once.

These functions are adding a spread operator to copy the state and then update the key 'facilityRating' or 'staffRating' with the new value of 'rating'.  I'm also doing a lambda here to take care of binding.

It also looks like your form is reseting because you're replacing the state instead of adding to it.  Use the spread operator again.

```
handleChange(event) {
        const formState = Object.assign({}, this.state.form);
        formState[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
        this.setState({ ...this.state, form: formState });
        console.log(formState);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks JD! I will try this out later. I'm still a novice with React. Much appreciated.

Comment: Awesome, I tested the code last night and it seemed to work out in my test project.  Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: I tried it out. The rating remains and doesn't reset, which is awesome. I'm just not getting my ratings for either Facility or Staff into the form state. Also, after I rate the Facility and then rate Staff, the Facility changes to the Staff's rating. React is even more complicated for me now that i'm using this other component React-Rating.

Comment: I did a basic example initially for your rating... The reason why the ratings were changing synchronously was because both of the ratings were pointing to the same value in the state. Sorry I overlooked that on your question. Now that I split the function in two, each function will handle the value in the store it is associated with and your information will be stored in form at its required location. If you start looking at these additional libraries and really pick them apart, you'll see its mostly the same song and dance over and over again. It's all just syntax.

Comment: Thanks again John (I'm not sure why I called you JD before, sorry) for the help!!! I'll try this later and get back. There's a lot to learn from you. I've never done a spread operator so I'm going to read up on that. And how you wrote the rating functions, I've never seen an arrow function like yours. I've done arrow functions but never with an equal sign between the function name and the parameter: handleStaffRatingChange = (rating)

Comment: Sorry, was away from this project. I added it in but I'm not sure how to check with a console.log statement that the ratings are in the form state. I haven't tied the back end yet

Comment: Try console.log (this.state)... it'll print out the object.  I'd put it in the componentWillMount function so it'll tell you the state each time.

Comment: It's working. I connected my frontend to the database and they all go in! Thanks so much for your help. :)